# Making a live photo slideshow

Tags: angular, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I need a little help with my project.

I need to place a TV monitor on a shop, and display there a slideshow of photos.
For that I bought a Raspberry Pi 3 to connect to the TV via hdmi, installed Samba server and shared a folder with my pc. So far so good.

Now I need a way to "listen" to a directory, and bind the changes to my gallery, so if I add photos to the folder it automatically adds them to the slideshow, and if I delete photos it deletes them from the slideshow.

Of course - all that should be done without the need to refresh the page, because no keyboard or mouse is going to be connected to the RasPi.

I'm going to build the gallery using Angular2.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Looks similar to what I was developing a few days back ! I registered and used a Flickr API and Secret Key to map the photos directory to my Flickr Account. Now I just add/remove the photos from my Flickr app on my mobile/desktop and the changes get updated when the script is run again.

It is still under development and a lot of things have been taken over from the net and synced to perfection. Just that the auto run on bootup feature (Chron) is pending.

**download_flickr.py:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 

import flickrapi
import requests
import os
import re

FLICKR_KEY = "0585ef7a*****************" #Your Flickr Key
FLICKR_SECRET = "469fe1e********"  #Secret Key
USER_ID = "9741****@**"    
SET_ID = "721576********"

def make_url(photo):
    # url_template = "http://farm{farm-id}.staticflickr.com/
    #                 {server-id}/{id}_{secret}_[mstzb].jpg"
photo['filename'] = "%(id)s_%(secret)s_z.jpg" % photo
url = ("http://farm%(farm)s.staticflickr.com/%(server)s/%(filename)s" 
       % photo)
return url, photo['filename']

def main():
    #get new imaged from flickr
    print " ---> Requesting photos..."
    count = 0
    update = False
    flickr = flickrapi.FlickrAPI(FLICKR_KEY, FLICKR_SECRET)
    photos = flickr.walk_set(SET_ID)
    for photo in photos:
        count += 1
        url, filename = make_url(photo.attrib)
        path = '/home/pi/photoframe/flickr/%s' % filename
    try:
        image_file = open(path)
        print " ---> Already have %s" % url
    except IOError:
        print " ---> Downloading %s" % url
        r = requests.get(url)      
        image_file = open(path, 'w')
        image_file.write(r.content)
        image_file.close()
        update = True

#check to see if it needs to remove photos from folder
filelist = os.listdir("/home/pi/photoframe/flickr")
if count < len(filelist):
    print " ---> Removing photos"
    for f in filelist:
        pics = flickr.walk_set(SET_ID)
        print f
        for pic in pics:
            url, filename = make_url(pic.attrib)
            matchObj = re.match(f, filename)
            if matchObj:
                print " ---> Found %s, matched %s" %(f,filename)
                break
        else:
            print " ---> Deleting %s" %f
            os.remove("/home/pi/photoframe/flickr/%s" %f)
            update = True    

#if it added or removed a photo, update slideshow
if update == True:
    print " ---> Restarting slideshow"
    os.system("sh kill $(ps aux | grep '[f]eh' | awk '{print $2}')")
    os.system("sh /bin/script_slideshow")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**kills:**

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -z "$1" ]; then

PROCESS=$1

PIDS= ps ax | grep $PROCESS | sed -e "s/.*killp.*//" -e "s/ *\ ([0-9]\         {$.*/\1/" | grep -v "^$"

if [ ! -z "$PIDS" ]; then

echo Killing $PROCESS pid=$PIDS

kill -9 $PIDS

else

echo No process $PROCESS in process list

fi

else

echo Usage : $0 process_name

fi
```

**scripy_slideshow:**

```
DISPLAY=:0.0 XAUTHORITY=/home/pi/.Xauthority feh -Z -F -z -Y -D 3 /home/pi/photoframe/flickr &
```

Now, just run the download_flickr.py file and if everything goes well, you will have the image in your display.

P.S: You need to register and get the Flickr API and secret keys from -https://www.flickr.com/services/apps/create/